# Connecting Lenovo E545 laptop to HP ZR2740W display - low resolution

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, resolution, external-display

I have Lenovo E545 laptop. It has VGA & HDMI video outputs. AMD Radeon HD 8450G Graphics

Display: HP ZR2740W It has DVI-D and DisplayPort inputs.

First I bought following cable:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004C9P9TM/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C9P9TM)

Didn't work, then I realized it's not bi-directional.

So, I bought this cable:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004CBDY42/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CBDY42)
High speed, dual link, 4k, etc.

Now it works. Laptop properly shows display model. But it only allows for maximum of 1280x720 resolution. It's not in "dual" or "extended" mode. Straight "projector" mode.

How do I make this laptop drive display at full 2560x1440 resolution?

I suspect it can't (but can't find definite specs) but little upset because my 3yo W510 does it no poroblem (via Display Port) and so is my little X230 (with Display Port)..

Comment: Does Windows recognize the display, or is it calling it a "default display" or "generic HDMI display"?

Comment: Yes, it shows display model properly

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Windows Screen Resolution window? With the problem display selected? Right-click on your Desktop, then click on "Screen Resolution".

Comment: I don't have access to it (its in the office) but under display it properly says "HP ZR2740w" and under Resolution it has "1280x720(recommended)" and this is max value

Comment: I've exhausted my ideas at the moment, sorry. Hopefully you can get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called support - neither DVI nor VGA can support this resolution. Replaced laptop with other model